# IndexError: list index out of range (shutil)

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

I used this code to copy and rename images with .png extension from src directory (and its sub-directories) to dst dirrectory and I got this error.

When I try the code on windows, it shows permission denied error and when I try it on Ubuntu, it shows this error as written in the title.

```
import os
import shutil
import pandas as pd
lst_files = []
for dir_name,sub_dir_list, file_list in os.walk('MURA-v1.1/valid    /XR_WRIST/'):         #For all body parts in train & valid sets
    for file_name in file_list:
        if ".png" in file_name.lower():
            lst_files.append(os.path.join(dir_name, file_name))
for i in range (len(lst_files)):
    a, b, c = lst_files[i].split('\\')[0], lst_files[i].split('\\')[1],     lst_files[i].split('\\')[2]
    lst_files[i] = a + '/' + b + '/' + c
    id, bin, img = lst_files[i].split('/')[-3],     lst_files[i].split('/')[-2], lst_files[i].split('/')[-1]
    src = lst_files[i]
    dest = '/home/mahmood/Desktop/MURA-v1.1/valid/WRIST/'
    #os.chdir(dest)
    stt=id+"_"+bin+"_"+img
    shutil.copy(src,dest)
    shutil.move(dest+c,dest+stt)
    #os.rename(img, stt)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Data_restructure.py", line 14, in <module>
    a, b, c = lst_files[i].split('\\')[0], lst_files[i].split('\\')[1],     lst_files[i].split('\\')[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error in your code is due to the fact that you are using Linux/Unix style paths (having `/` as directory separator) in `os.walk()`, and trying to replace a backslash `\` off it, which is not usually possible.

What your code is intending to do is:-

1. Do a lookup in a given directory and find files who have `.png` in their filename
2. Upon finding one, add the location of the file to your list `lst_files`

Later in your code, you are trying to split the location of files in your `lst_files` list, by `\` string, which is not possible. Why?

Because, the directory location's in your list will have a syntax similar to `root_dir/sub_dir/filename.ext`, as you can see there is not backslash in the filename (and how could there be as in Linux a `/` is used as directory separator). So when you will try the operation `lst_files[i].split('\\')[0]` and index error will always arise, because the string could never split (as it won't contain a `\` in general).

**Rectification:-**

Change `lst_files[i].split('\\')[0]` to `lst_files[i].split('/')[0]` if you're intending to use this program on Linux OS

**Some Improvements:-**

you are using wrong way of finding whether a file is of `.png` extention or not. In your code if a file name is `abed.png.going.txt` (a text file which contains `.png` clause in its name) that file will also be accounted as a `.png` file in your code, which is obviously not right. Instead use `os.path.splitext()` as it takes in a file location and returns a list containing its filename, and its extension separately.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, now I think I return to the same error of windows but in Linux style:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'MURA-v1.1/valid/XR_WRIST'